# TypeError: ethers.getContract is not a function | Lesson 07 Hardhat

Tags: solidity, blockchain, wallets, javascript, hardhat

I'm Following Patrick Collins's Blockchain Course from Youtube.
On lesson 07 at timestamp 11:18:00, I run the following command to run test

```
yarn hardhat test
```

I get the following error

```
1) "before each" hook for "sets the aggregator addresses correctly"
```

```
TypeError: ethers.getContract is not a function
```

following is my Solidity code

```
const { deployments, getNamedAccounts, network } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("ethers")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

describe("FundMe", function () {
    let fundMe
    let mockV3Aggregator
    let deployer
    beforeEach(async () => {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })
    describe("constructor", function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async () => {
            const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address)
        })
    })
    describe("fund", function () {
        it("Fails if you dont send enough ETH", async () => {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more ETH!"
            )
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139409/hardhat-deploy-typeerror-ethers-getcontract-is-not-a-function) about installing hardhat-deploy-ethers doesn't work for you,

You could either try using .getContractAt for "ethers v6" or adding these statements to your hardhat.config.js file.

```
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers');
require('hardhat-deploy-ethers');
```

Additional details can be found in the "Discussions" section of the course repo [here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/5832)