# How to get deployed contract address with ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, typescript, typechain

I using hardhat deploy (TypeScript) and am deploying two contracts: the first is a mock ERC20 token and a second is a crowdfunding contract that uses the mock when on a hardhat chain/localhost.

I am trying to get the address of the MockToken contract for my Crowdfund contract.

I used to just use:

```typescript
mockToken: MockToken = await ethers.getContract('MockToken');
mockTokenAddress = mockToken.address
```

Now I am getting the error in TS that "Property 'getContract' does not exist on type" for ethers

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this? The scripts are labeled 00__deployMockToken and 01__deployCrowdfund so the mock is always deployed before the Crowdfund.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139409/hardhat-deploy-typeerror-ethers-getcontract-is-not-a-function

Comment: oh that is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by @AlexanderHerranz is for ethers v5, for newer versions of hardhat that use ethers v6 you can get the deployed address using the async getAddress() method as shown below:

```typescript
const MyContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract")

const myContract = (await MyContractFactory.connect(signer).deploy());
await myContract.waitForDeployment();
const myContractDeployedAddress = await myContract.getAddress();
```

Comment: Have my upvote, I was looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a contract, and get the new contract address, using Ethers.js' ContractFactory.

```
import { ContractFactory } from 'ethers';

const factory = new ContractFactory(contractAbi, contractByteCode);

// If your contract requires constructor args, you can specify them here
const contract = await factory.deploy(deployArgs);

console.log(contract.address);
console.log(contract.deployTransaction);
```

You can check out more about Contract Factory, from ethers, here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/

Comment: hmmm yes I understand how to deploy the contract but how do I get the contract if it is already deployed and I just dont have the address?

Comment: In the provided example  you are deploying the contract and getting the address (contract.address) afterwards. The error you see is because you are not referencing to an already deployed contract.