# Getting the Error: "Could not decode result data"

Tags: hardhat, testing

I am trying to run a FundMe.sol contract test on hardhat and I am getting the following error:

```
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getPriceFeed", "signature": "getPriceFeed()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.6.0)
```

This is the test file I am running:

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");

describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe;
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
        fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer);
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        );
    });
    
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed();
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address);
        })
    })
```

The issue appears to be on line:
`const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed()`
The `getPriceFeed()` function does exist and it should be using the data from the mock aggregator deployment. However, I keep on getting the same error. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getContractAt` use `getContract` and make sure that *hardhat.config.js* have `require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")`

Answer (score 0):

With `fundMe.getPriceFeed()` you're calling the `fundMe` contract, but it's actually the deployer:

```
fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer);
```

So you need to put the address of the contract there instead of `deployer`. Unless you meant to call `mockV3Aggregator.getPriceFeed()`.

Comment: So how would I grab the contract address after running "await deployments.fixture(["all"])"?

Comment: In general you get the address with `(await deployments.get("FundMe")).address`. I'm thinking also that `fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer);` (`getContract` instead of `getContractAt`) may work, since should grab the address automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I just get the error `TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.1)` when I try to use .address. And I have tried to use `fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer);` , but it tells me that ethers.getContract does not exist.

Comment: Weird because the syntax should be correct, as you can see in the docs https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#testing-deployed-contracts. Maybe you have the same problem as this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139409/hardhat-deploy-typeerror-ethers-getcontract-is-not-a-function ?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when You try to interact with contract address that is empty
You can check it with

```
if (await hre.ethers.provider.getCode(CONTRACT_ADDRESS) == '0x'){
//at this address there is nothing to interact with
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/97624)